# What is the DLookup and Nz() format for when field in table is Null?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a DLookup formula that fetches the [Model] from MyTable. Everything works until the value for fieldname [Model] is blank.

I get a Runtime Error 94 about how it doesn't understand null information.

I have tried using Nz() function. It is confusing to use these functions when I have so many double and single quotes.

This is what I have.

```
Dim other as String
other = DLookup("[Model]", "[Part Number & Part Name]", "[Part Number]='" & Forms![Press 2]![Containment - Press 2 subform].Form![Part Number] & "'")

If other <> "" Then
    Me.[Model].Value = other
Else
    Me.Model.Value = "NA"
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *Nz* and reduce the code:

```
Dim other as String

other = Nz(DLookup("[Model]", "[Part Number & Part Name]", "[Part Number]='" & Forms![Press 2]![Containment - Press 2 subform].Form![Part Number] & "'"), "NA")   
Me![Model].Value = other
```

Comment: That still leaves buggy behaviour if `Forms![Press 2]![Containment - Press 2 subform].Form![Part Number]` is null, since then the `DLookUp` will look for a zero-length string.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: No. The _Null_ will result in this criteria: `[Part Number]=''` which has no match, therefore _DLookup_ will return _Null_. This is handled by _Nz_ which then will return `"NA"` - as requested by the questioneer.

Comment: Unless there are entries with zero-length strings, of course, which can very well exist if you use similar code to insert records, leading to unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks @Gustav that works perfectly. I knew I was close but could figure out how to line us Nz and all the & "'". Even if the values are Null, it replaces the value with "NA". Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, _Nz_ - _DLookup_ often forms an effective combo.

Answer (score 1):

There are two tricky places for null values in your code:

1. If `Forms![Press 2]![Containment - Press 2 subform].Form![Part Number]` is null, the `DLookUp` will be processed incorrectly, since you're including it as a string.

   Fix: use the form value as a parameter, this also avoids SQL injection errors:

   ```
   other = DLookup("[Model]", "[Part Number & Part Name]", "[Part Number]= Forms![Press 2]![Containment - Press 2 subform].Form![Part Number]")
   ```
2. You're storing the `DLookUp` result in a string. You can either use `Nz` here to return a different string, or concatenate a zero-lenght string with the `DLookUp` result to process a Null value as a zero-length string:

   ```
   other = VbNullString & DLookup("[Model]", "[Part Number & Part Name]", "[Part Number]= Forms![Press 2]![Containment - Press 2 subform].Form![Part Number]")
   ```

That should cover all places where nulls can interfere with this part of code.